# How to execute JS from JSP Page?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm executing the following line of code on page load for a JSP page in JavaScript.

```
alert("test");
```

I'm trying to debug it but it's not working any idea what could cause this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: implementing means wen I m writing the code simple , alert("test"); on load of JSP, I did not get output means there is nothing alert dialog box is showing and if I m doing the same things with HTML page, alert dialog box is showing. y JS is not working for JSP page and how we can use JS for JSP page

Comment: Please post the code of your JSP.

Comment: actually we don't have any JSP code, there is JSP page and there is one tool in which we writing code in JS to fetch the element value or put some value in element... so wen I m writing code against JSP page in the tool its not working and if same thing i m doing with HTML page its working

Comment: Debugging involves breaking down the problem in smaller parts. I'd suggest that you look for what code your tool creates to track this down. You need to find out **what** causes your problem: The tool, or JavaScript or the JSP.

Comment: 1- we writing code in JS, so JS is not problematic cause. 2- we are fetching the element data or putting some value in element using this tool to write JS code for HTML page so its working. it means tool is not a cause. 3- JSP is written on server side and we JS works on browser (Client Side), this may be a reason. so my question is this how we can consume my JS over the JSP page

Comment: Hi dear, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Without having seen the code of the JSP page it is hard to guess, why the JavaScript is not executed.

> I did not get output means there is nothing alert dialog box is
>   showing and if I m doing the same things with HTML page, alert dialog
>   box is showing.

A valid HTML file is a valid JSP file, too. So if you have a working HTML file and just rename it's extension to .jsp, it is a valid JSP file that should work the same way as your HTML does. There's no difference in embedding JavaScript in HTML or JSP.

E.g. this is a valid JSP Page with JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSP test</title>
        <script>
            alert("test");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>JSP test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```